# Save form data in Database using classes

Tags: php, database, forms, class

I have a form. (Registration.php)

```
<form action="reservation.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" class="pure-form" id="form" method="POST"> 
<label for="initials">Initials:</label><input type="text" name="initials" id="initials" placeholder="initials" required><br />
<label for="firstname">First name:</label><input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="firstname" required><br />
<label for="surname">Surname:</label><input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" placeholder="surname" required><br />
<label for="country">Country:</label><input type="text" name="country" id="country" placeholder="country" required><br />
<label for="state">State:</label><input type="text" name="state" id="state" placeholder="state" ><br />
<label for="province">Province:</label><input type="text" name="province" id="province" placeholder="province" required><br />
<label for="city">City:</label><input type="text" name="city" id="city" placeholder="city" required><br />
<label for="houseadress">Houseadress:</label><input type="text" name="houseadress" id="houseadress" placeholder="houseadress" required><br />
<label for="phone">Phone:</label><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="phone" required><br />
<label for="email">E-mail:</label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email" required><br />
<input type="submit" value="register" name="register">
</form>
```

And I have a class: (client.class.php)

```
class Client{
    private $clientID;
    private $initials;
    private $name;
    private $surname;
    private $country;
    private $state;
    private $province;
    private $city;
    private $houseadress;
    private $phone;
    private $email;

    public function __construct($clientID, $initials, $name, $surname, $country, $state, $province, $city, $houseadress, $phone, $email) {
        $this->clientID = $clientID;
        $this->initials = $initials;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->surname = $surname;
        $this->country = $country;
        $this->state = $state;
        $this->province = $province;
        $this->city = $city;
        $this->houseadress = $houseadress;
        $this->phone = $phone;
        $this->email = $email;
    }
}
```

And a Database connection: (database.php)

```
class Database {
    public $pdo;

    public function __construct() {
        // Connection information
        $host   = 'localhost:3307';
        $dbname = 'californiahotel';
        $user   = 'root';
        $pass   = 'usbw';

        // Attempt DB connection
        try
        {
            $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            //echo 'Successfully connected to the database!';
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

    }
     public function __destruct()
    {
        // Disconnect from DB
        $this->pdo = null;
        //echo 'Successfully disconnected from the database!';
    }
}
```

I have been looking for weeks now to find out how to get the form data to the class (Client) and then to the class(Database) and then save it to the database! But I Didn't find anything that I needed.
Perhaps someone can explain how it can be done?

Comment: Do you have a table, that could store this information in the database?

Comment: I have a database with all the columns as the form! Named Client.

Comment: yes i think you can use the whole object to insert it, however i;m not sure if it will work on private properties. just try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add all `get` methods for your `Client` class**.
For example:

```
class Client{
    public function getClientID(){
      return $this->clientID;
    }
  }
```

**Add `addClient` method to your `Database` class**

```
class Database {
  public function addClient($client){

    //Get all vars
    $initials = $client->getInitials();
    $name = $client->getName();
    $surname = $client->getSurname();
    $country = $client->getCountry();
    $state = $client->getState();
    $province = $client->getProvince();
    $city = $client->getCity();
    $houseaddress = $client->getHouseAddress();
    $phone = $client->getPhone();
    $email = $client->getEmail()

    //Create the query
    $sth = $this->pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO Client (Initials, Name, Surname, Country, State, Province, City, HouseAddress, Phone, Email) VALUES (:initials, :name, :surname, :country, :state, :province, :city, :houseaddress, :phone, :email)');
    $sth->bindParam(':initials', $initials);
    $sth->bindParam(':name', $name);
    $sth->bindParam(':surname', $surname);
    $sth->bindParam(':country', $country);
    $sth->bindParam(':state', $state);
    $sth->bindParam(':province', $province);
    $sth->bindParam(':city', $city);
    $sth->bindParam(':houseaddress', $houseaddress);
    $sth->bindParam(':phone', $phone);
    $sth->bindParam(':email', $email);

    //Execute the query
    $sth->execute();
  }
}
```

**In reservation.php**

```
$initials = $_POST['initials'];
$name = $_POST['firstname'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$province = $_POST['province'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$houseaddress = $_POST['houseaddress'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$client = new Client("", $initials, $name, $surname, $country, $state, $province, $city, $houseadress, $phone, $email);
$database = new Database();
$database->addClient($client);
```

Comment: I get the Error: Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\Users\Arjan\Spullen\Programmas\PHP server\root\Ala\Project\Project\Arjanoskam\database.php At each line of the Sth->Bindparam(':Something', $client->getSomething());

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use reflection to get private and protected class properties. The following is a simple function that I use to return an instance of a class. The first argument is the class name and the second argument is the array data, in your case it will be the form data. The registeration class must have the same variables names as your form.

```
    public function toEntity($entityName, array $data){
    $entity = new $entityName();

    $refClass = new ReflectionClass($entity);
    $properties = $refClass->getProperties();

    foreach($properties as $property){
        $property->setAccessible(true);
        $propertyName = $property->getName();

        if(array_key_exists($propertyName, $data)){ 
            $value = $data[$propertyName];
            $property->setValue($entity, $value);
        }
    }
    return $entity; 
}
```